# How we can use 2 if functions on submit button in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-selected-items

I have a requirement out 10 questions user has to answer at least any 6 questions and also there is another tabbed section where out of 12 Questions user has to answer at least 3 Questions otherwise the form should not get submitted or an error message should Popup.

I have tried below functions.

```
If(
    CountIf(
        [
            DataCardValue13,
            DataCardValue14,
            DataCardValue15,
            DataCardValue16,
            DataCardValue17,
            DataCardValue18,
            DataCardValue19,
            DataCardValue20,
            DataCardValue21,
            DataCardValue22
        ],
        !IsBlank(Value)
    ) >= 6,
    Notify(
        "Please Answer atleast 6 rapid Fire Questions",
        NotificationType.Error
    ),
    If(
        CountIf(
            [
                DataCardValue23,
                DataCardValue24,
                DataCardValue25,
                DataCardValue26,
                DataCardValue30,
                DataCardValue31,
                DataCardValue32,
                DataCardValue34,
                DataCardValue35,
                DataCardValue36,
                DataCardValue37,
                DataCardValue38
            ],
            !IsBlank(Value)
        ) >= 3,
        Notify("Please Answer atleast 3 Questions"),
        SubmitForm(Form1)
    )m
)
```

Seems like it is not working and form is getting submitted even after the columns are blank. But if I am trying single if condition it is working. Kindly help me on this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the exact input value in the formula.

**For example**:

If you are using all text inputs, you have to use:

```
DataCardValue32.Text
```

Instead of just `DataCardValue32`.

If you are using drop down controls, use:

```
DataCardValue32.Selected.Value
```

You have to pass the correct values to the formula.

Also, you may want to use [Table function in Power Apps](Table function in Power Apps) to create a proper table of value instead of wrapping them withing `[]`.